# use e2e protractor test http result for url

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor

i need a test to certify the http request results(only json) is right,How do I get it,or use other ways

```
describe('test', function() {

    it('get a json', function() {
        browser.get('http://.../consumer/2/indexinfo');

    });
});
```

i don't get it because of the result a json not use `element`

Answer (score 2):

You can use request to get a json response:

```
require("request")({
  url: 'http://.../consumer/2/indexinfo',
  json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
    console.log(body);
  }
})
```

Comment: i need  `Integration Testing`

Answer (score 1):

Protractor is used for end to end (e2e) testing, with one end being user interaction (like a click), and the other end being DOM changes (like text updating). You should be asserting for DOM changes like text updating, not testing the JSON object used to update the DOM.

If you must test the response though, it is possible via the NPM module [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

Comment: protractor could  use `element` get  DOM why don't  get  json

Comment: The DOM and a server response object are two different things.

Comment: thank you ,i found `qunit` should  i need,and i'm chinese, English is wrong